# selenium user-extension verify example

Tags: javascript, selenium

Does someone have an example of a verify function for use in Javascript user-extensions.js ?

Or any documentation reference?

The verify term is used loosely in the all the docs and examples Ive seen.

I want to write a verify function that does not abort the test.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Sorry you didn't Luke my questions(s).I will keep your points in mind if I use this again.